# How to get a protobuf repeated field builder in Java?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, builder

I want to convert an object of another format into a protobuf, knowing the protobuf's Descriptors.  It's easy to do for regular fields or even a nested field.  But, I'm running into a problem for repeated fields.

```
message Foo {
    optional MsgA a = 1;
    repeated MsgB b = 2;
}
```

For "MsgA a", the code bld.getFieldBuilder(field) works:

```
Foo.Builder bld = Foo.newBuilder();
Descriptors.Descriptor msgDesc = Foo.getDescriptor();
List<Descriptors.FieldDescriptor> fields = msgDesc.getFields();    
for (Descriptors.FieldDescriptor field : fields) {
    Message.Builder subBld = bld.getFieldBuilder(field);
    // set foreign value xyz using subBld
    // subBld.setFleld(subfield1, xyz);
}
```

But for "MsgB b", the same code throws "UnsupportedOperationException: getFieldBuilder() called on a non-Message type."

I understand the repeated field is a list, I may set each one separately.  But, how do I get a builder first?  Is there a clean and easy way to do the similar?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: I've answered as best I can, but it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 8):

You don't get a builder for the repeated field itself - you call `Builder.addRepeatedField(field, value)` etc. To get a builder for the *type* of the repeated field, you can use:

```
Builder builder = bld.newBuilderForField(field)
```

If you want to modify an existing value, you can use `Builder.getRepeatedFieldBuilder(field, index)`.

To create an instance to start with, you can use `Builder.newBuilderForField`:

```
Message.Builder subBld = bld.newBuilderForField(field);
// Now modify subBld, then...
bld.addRepeatedField(field, subBld.build());
```

Comment: Sure, but in order to construct the 'value', I need to first instantiate/obtain a MsgB.Builder.  I only know the field descriptor.

Comment: @Nathan: See my edit - I think that should work. It's been a long time since I've done anything like this with the Java protobuf reflection API...

Comment: Jon, that works.  Thanks a lot!  Strange, 'get' doesn't but 'new' works.

Comment: Tried to +1, but don't have enough reputation yet :)  Thanks, again!

Comment: @scottxiao: I suggest you ask a new question showing what you've tried and what happened. It's a long time since I've looked at the Java protobuf code, but I'll do what I can.